# C++ Timer - Start & Stop works - Restart doesn't

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer, restart, conditional-variable

I am having a trouble exiting a thread using a Restart function. When calling Stop it exits the thread, but Restart which calls Stop and then Start right after - doesn't exit the thread -> calls Start and creates a new thread.

Thanks. Any help would be really helpful and appreciated.

Dummy code to show the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

bool running = false;

unsigned int interval = 5000;

condition_variable cv_work;
mutex mu_cv_work;

void Start()
{
    unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mu_cv_work);
    running = true;
    lock.unlock();
    thread([]{
        cout << "new thread" << '\n';
        while (running)
        {
            cout << "work..." << '\n';
            unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mu_cv_work);
            cout << "sleep" << '\n';
            if (cv_work.wait_for(lock, chrono::milliseconds(interval), []{return running == false;}))
            {
                cout << "exit thread" << '\n';
                return;
            }
            cout << "done sleeping" << '\n';
        }
    }).detach();
}

void Stop()
{
    unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mu_cv_work);
    running = false;
    lock.unlock();
    cv_work.notify_one();
}

void Restart()
{
    Stop();
    Start();
}

int main()
{
    Start();
    cout << "press to Stop" << '\n';
    cin.get();
    Stop();                             // Stop actually exits the Thread
    cout << "press to Start" << '\n';
    cin.get();
    Start();
    cout << "press to Restart" << '\n';
    cin.get();
    Restart();                         // Stop doesn't exit the Thread (Restart calls Stop() and Start())

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
press to Stop
new thread
work...
sleep
                      // KEY PRESS
exit thread
press to Start
                      // KEY PRESS
new thread
work...
sleep
press to Restart
                      // KEY PRESS
new thread
work...
sleep
done sleeping
work...
sleep
```

Expected output:

```
press to Stop
new thread
work...
sleep
                      // KEY PRESS
exit thread    
press to Start
                      // KEY PRESS
new thread
work...
sleep    
press to Restart
                      // KEY PRESS    
exit thread             // THIS LINE
new thread
work...
sleep
done sleeping
work...
sleep
```

Comment: When you call `Stop()` how do you know when the thread has ended? How do you know that it has ended before you start a new one? If two threads are running concurrently, which one receives the condition? To be sure, you shouldn't `detach` it so that you can `join` it in `Stop()`.

Comment: Adding to that, what is going to prevent someone from doing `Start(); Start();` ? It submit there are significant design problems from inception.

Comment: @WhozCraig it's just a dummy version of the code. I got it no worries ;) But thanks anyways

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I added if joinable() then join() and it outputs what the expected output is, but crashes right after that because of "terminate called without an active exception"

Comment: Side note: About [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You designed your threads this way – `stop` terminates the thread, and at this point it is gone – `start` creates a new one and cannot do anything else as the other one is lost.

Worse: those two threads (new and old one) might overlap in execution for some time.

You already have included a loop within your thread – now make sure that you do *not* exit this loop if you are going to restart your thread. You currently included a `return` within your code – this makes the `running` the test for `running` in your while loop obsolete anyway. We now can change a bit, reusing the `running` variable for another purpose; additionally we might use a three-fold state, possibly defined in an enum:

```
enum ThreadState // ThreadCommand?
{
    Active,  // or Running, or Run, if named ...Command
             // choose whichever names appear most suitable to you...
    Restart,
    Exit,    // or Stop
};
```

Now you'll set the state to `Active` on starting a thread, on stopping you'd set the state to `Exit` and notify the thread as is while on re-start you'd set the state appropriately, *again* notifying the thread. I personally would use an intermediate function for:

```
void stop()
{
    notify(Exit);
}
void restart()
{
    notify(Restart);
}
void notify(ThreadState state)
{
    // set the global state/command
    // notify the thread as done now
}
```

Now you'll consider the state in your loop:

```
[]()
{
    // endless loop, you return anyway...
    for(;;)
    {
        // working code as now
        // checking the notification as now, however the lambda now
        // checks the global state:
        if(wait_for(..., []() { return globalState != Active; })
        {
            if(globalState == Restart)
            {
                std::cout << "thread restarting" << std::endl;
                continue; // the loop!
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "thread exiting" << std::endl;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware, though, that you should re-initialise the state of local variables as well (it's a restart, isn't it?) – at least as far as these don't need to be *intentionally* persisted over multiple thread starts. A pretty simple approach to achieve correct re-initialisation might be packing the variables into a double loop:

```
[]()
{
    // all variables of which the states should be persisted over multiple
    // starts – well, RE-starts only for now!!!
    // for all starts, you currently rely on global variables

    for(;;)
    {
        // all variables that should get initialised with every restart
        // they get destroyed and newly constructed with every loop run

        for(;;) // another nested loop...
        {
            // ...
            if(wait_for(/* as above*/))
            {
                if(globalState == Restart)
                {
                    break; // the INNER loop!
                           // we'd then continue the outer one
                           // achieving the re-initalisation
                }
                else
                {
                    return; // still terminating the thread
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I still recommend to pack all this code into its own class. This comes with several advantages:

- You can avoid global variables entirely.
- You can prevent access to variables and functions that should not be accessed directly by the user (e.g. the `globalState` variable and the `notify` function, the mutex, the condition variable and possibly many others).
- You can start more than one thread in parallel, each thread now has its own set of variables:

```
class TaskRunner // (or whatever name suites you...)
{
public:
    // all of these: containing the code as above, but accessing member variables!
    start(); // the lambda would need to capture this now: [this]() { ... }!
    stop();
    restart();
private:
    enum ThreadCommand { /* ... */ }; // not of interest outside the class
    ThreadCommand m_command;
    // mutex, condition variable and whatever else is not of interest outside

    // I'd store the thread in a local variable as well!
    // the advantage of, is that you can check the tread
    // with `joinable`, though this means that you
    // either need to join the thread as well OR delay
    // detaching until calling stop
    std::thread m_thread;

    notify(ThreadCommand command)
    {
        m_command = command;
        // notify the thread runner
    }

    // I'd prefer an ordinary member function over the lambda:
    void run()
    {
        // with the double loop as above, though there might not be variables
        // any more persisted over re-starts only; you might instead entirely
        // rely on member variables...
    }
}

void ThreadRunner::start()
{
    if(m_thread.joinable())
    {
        // appropriate error handling...
    }
    else
    {
        // with separate run function instead of lambda:
        m_thread = std::thread(&ThreadRunner::run, this);
    }
}

void ThreadRunner::stop()
{
    // stopping thread as above

    if(m_thread.joinable())
    {
        m_thread.join(); // waits for thread completion, assuring some
                         // potential cleanup work correctly to be done
                         // prevents, too, two threads overlap provided
                         // subsequent `start` is not called from yet another
                         // thread (you might store thread id of last successful
                         // caller and check it to prevent such asituation)

        // alternatively you might detach, with all its disadvantages
        // but that's far less recommendable
    }
}
```

You should call `stop` from within the destructor as well to make sure a thread is correctly stopped if the `ThreadRunner` instance runs out of scope without `stop` having been explicitly called:

```
ThreadRunner::~ThreadRunner() // declare in class as well or define directly there
{
    stop();
}
```

Note: Any code above is entirely untested; if you find a bug, please fix yourself.

Comment: Thank you! Managed to get it working with your help and explanation. :-)